# HTML5/Javascript Adding Values From Head to Body

Tags: javascript, html, head

I need to be able to add variables declared in the script from the head of my code to the body of my code. More specifically need to be able to get the information that the user typed into the script and put that in place of something that would go in the body. Here is **some** code of what I am trying to explain:

```
<head>
<script>
var x="Type something here";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>I do love "var x"</p>
</body>
```

Essentially what I'm looking to do is take my variable x and put it into the body of the paragraph. The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to add something to the body of the html without adding in the the quotes outside of something like var x or put part of a what I want in the paragraph and then add "var x" with a "+" sign without adding the "+" to the body of the paragraph. I know this is an easy thing but I suck at it and I've spent about 6 hours trying to figure this out. I appreciate the replies ahead of time. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use innerHTML http://jsfiddle.net/VasnG/

Comment: Thank you. Do I use innerHTML in the head or the body? If it is in the head what command would I put into the body to add it to the body?

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var x="Type something here";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="the_spot"></p>
        <script>
           document.getElementById( 'the_spot' ).innerHTML = "I do love " + x;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

what i did above is use a javascript function `innerHTML`. this function changes the content of any element you specify. however, this function completely erases the existing contents of that element and re-write the contents you specified, in this case, "I do love Type something here". if you do not wish your existing contents to get erased, use `append` or `prepend` functions.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Script should be inside body tag

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
<head>
<script>
var x="Type something here";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="var_x_modify">I do love "var x"</p>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('var_x_modify').innerHTML=document.getElementById('var_x_modify').innerHTML.replace(/"var x"/,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a script to do that.

```
<p id="var-x">I do love "var x"</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('var-x').innerHTML = "I do love " + x;
</script>
```

I also added an ID to the `<p>` to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<head>
<script>
var x="Type something here";
window.onLoad = function(){
   var el= document.querySelector("#idx");
   el.innerHTML= x;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>I do love <span id="idx"></span></p>
</body>
```